# Packaged Electron app can't find local module

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-modules, electron-builder

I have an Electron app, based off of the electron-react-boilerplate template project. In my app, I have a class in a `myClass.js` file in

`app/utils/myClass.js`

```
class MyClass {
// A bunch of stuff...
}
module.exports = MyClass;
```

I reference this class in a renderer process preload script.

`app/utils/preload.js`

```
const MyClass = require('./myClass.js');
```

Which I load in a renderer background worker process like so

```
const workerWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: require('path').join(__dirname, 'utils', 'preload.js')
    }
  });
```

When I run the app in development/debug mode, the `MyClass` module is found just fine and all code works. However, when I go to package the app (using electron-builder) and install on Windows, running the code causes the following error:

`{"code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND","requireStack":["C:\\Users\\Cooper\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\my-app\\resources\\app\\utils\\myClass.js","C:\\Users\\Cooper\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\my-app\\resources\\app\\utils\\preload.js"]}`

For some reason, the app can't find my MyClass module, even though I can confirm the files are in the appropriate directory in the packaged .asar archive. I've tried many different ways of `require`ing MyClass but to no avail.

Why can't my packaged app find my MyClass module? How can I resolve this? Worth noting my preoload.js script has no problem with any other dependency. I can do `require('electron')` without issue, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that the app wasn't ablet find the `MyClass` module, but instead it couldn't find a dependency within `MyClass`. electron-builder uses two package.json files. package.json at the project root, which is used during development and did include all of my dependencies as expected, but also a second /app/package.json which is used for when the app is packaged and deployed. This was missing a lot of my dependencies.

https://www.electron.build/tutorials/two-package-structure

Manually adding the required dependencies to that package.json file resolved the issue.